# Distinct Criteria on part of a composite primary key in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table report (class Report) that is identified with a composite primary key (class ReportPK)

```
@Embeddable
public class ReportPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="num")
    private int num;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="index")
    private String index;

    //Getters, setters, equals and hashCode methods 
}

@Entity
public class Report {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ReportPK id;

    //Other fields, getters .....
}
```

Here, a report is identified with a number and an index.

I want to retrieve reports with different number such that if I have these reports in the table :
(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A')
I will get as result (1, 'A') and (2, 'A') (not (1, 'B')).

I use this code but it returns a list of ReportPK instead of a list of Report, moreover it returns all the report (such as no distinct criteria was used)

```
List <Report> results = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Report.class)
            .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                .add( Projections.distinct(Projections.property("num")) )
            ).list();
```

If some have encountered a similar problem or have an idea about how to do it I appreciate his help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are expectin the Entity as a result but you are using projections.

If you want to get distict valeus then use:

```
getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Report.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

And if you want to refer to the embedded id of the entity you should add the id field name as a prefix f.e:

```
Restrictions.gt("id.num", 10);
```

Comment: When I use "getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Report.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list;" I get an empty list, do you know why?

Comment: try to make Report implenets Serializable

Comment: What is the sql generated by hibernate?

Comment: I am new using Hibernate and I don't know how to get the generated sql.

Comment: in your hibernate.cfg add <!--hibernate.cfg.xml -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

Comment: Is there a way to do it in java? (I used java configuration with spring)

Comment: Actually, I think that using this SQL query will maybe simplify the task : "Select num, MIN(`index`) AS `index` from report
group by num". 
Is there a way to retrieve reports list using this query or even retrieve Keys and after using them to retrieve reports list?

Comment: I used an Sql query and it works good :


    String sql = "SELECT r.* FROM (Select num, MIN(`index`) AS `index` from report group by num) AS ru, report r WHERE ru.num = r.num AND ru.index = r.index";

    NativeQuery<Report_t>  query = getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery(sql);

    query.addEntity(Report_t.class);

    List<Report_t> res = query.list();

Comment: ok good. just remembe that you loose portability when you use plain sql queries